# Include file.php + id. Is this possible with php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've built my site with php include and the index is as follows:

`Menu.php` (menu system)
`main.php` (Index site)
`footer.php` (footer obv.)

Anyway, when `main.php` (index) opens, I've added a news script that uses `$_GET` to fetch the news-data from our mysql database. This generates an ID for each news, and it shows only a few characters of the full news.

So, I've added a link in each news that says "Read more" to expand the news, it looks like this:

```
<a href="news.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>">Read More</a></p>
```

So, is there a way for me to include this site (replace `news.php?id=x` with `main.php`)?

It gives me syntax error when I'm trying to use `<?php include` in the link since it's already using `<?=$row['id']?>`.

The only help I got so far are people telling me to change the menu system to Javascript (Ajax, Jquery) but I'm not too familiar with this. Is there something I can do more simple than changing the menu to javascript?

Thanks for your help and understanding,

Have a great day!

Comment: I don't remember that `<?=$row['id']?>` is valid php syntax. Use `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` instead.

Comment: Well I want the link to follow an include of the news. The link I wrote does everything I need to do, except for including it into the main :/

Comment: @Martin: It's fine if `short_open_tag` is enabled in PHP.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, include basically adds the code of another file to the execution of the code you are using.  So if you already have the variable in you index file can just use it in your menu file.

If the menu file has to be loaded on it own sometimes you can do a conditional for the existence of the GET, then the existence of the variable in your index file, and finally if none of them exit, set a default value.

Comment: Well is there something I can write into the menu system?

Like 

case 'news' include("news.php?id=$row['id']");break;
default: include("main.php");break;

Would something like this work?

Comment: No, the include statement doesn't process query string variables.. It is a request to the hard drive not the web-server to attach code from the file selected.

Comment: So is there any way for me to do this in a simple way? I think I maybe have to look over ajax/jquery.. ?

Comment: var $rowID = $row['id'];
include('Menu.php')

now you can simply user $rowID with in the Menu.php file.  And if you want to be safe,  you can even add a null check to set a default value not to break your code.

$rowID = (is_null($rowID) ? default Value : $rowID);

So as I was saying before, you don't need to and can't pass a variable as a request query string because it is never being loaded as a request, it is being inserted into into your parent file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `main.php`, get the id value on `main.php`, pass it to your news function.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "change it to main.php" since main is the same as index body.

Maybe I'm just stupid :P

Answer (score 0):

leave your link as is, it's fine.
do not include main into news.

include only menu and footer into news.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. I can either show ONLY the news-item (the id of the news I want to read) or the header and footer :(

Comment: @Jaoza it should. If it isn't, you have to debug it